# didReceiveMemoryWarning removes cells/views from UITableView hierarchy

Tags: ios, uitableview, childviewcontroller, didreceivememorywarning

I have set up a `UITableView` in which each cell has a child `UIViewController`

I've tried reusing cells using `dequeueReusableCell(with identifier:)` and adding/removing child view controller on `willDisplay cell` and `didEndDisplaying cell` methods.

Another thing I preferred using was not dequeuing cells and storing/accessing them like this:

```
let cell: FeedCell
if let cached = feedCells[feedItem.uuid]{
   cell = cached
}else{
   cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FeedCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as! FeedCell
   cell.feedItem = feedItem
   feedCells[feedItem.uuid] = cell
}
```

So basically the property `feedCells` is a dictionary `[String: FeedCell]`, when I was reusing view controllers, it was `[String: UIViewController]`

I've identified that the key to my issue is this dictionary and `didReceiveMemoryWarning`

Whenever I receive a memory warning in the app, the visible cells or ViewControllers that are part of that dictionary get removed from view hierarchy even though they hold a `strong` reference in the dictionary. They do persist to live in the dictionary so I can reload the table view and show them again. Which I'm doing now on `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

But my concern is why are the views being removed from the hierarchy like this even though we've held a strong reference to them, and any way to prevent this?